# Solution verification: Integral of the conjugate equals the conjugate of the integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

For all $f(z)$ holomorphic in all $\mathbb C$ and every smooth curve $\gamma$, is it correct that:

$\overline {\int_\gamma f(z)dz}=\int_\gamma \overline { f(z)}dz$

My solution: If $f$ is holomorphic on all $\mathbb C$, then for every 2 endpoints $a,b$ in $\mathbb C$, and any $\gamma$ connecting them we get $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_a^b f(z)dz=F(b)-F(a)$, $F$ being $f$'s primitive function.

So $\overline {\int_\gamma f(z)dz}=\overline {F(b)-F(a)}=\overline {F(b)}-\overline {F(a)}$

And same with the RHS. Not sure if this is correct.

Sorry for my sketchy English, it isn't my native language.

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not correct. Choose

$\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb C, t\mapsto ti$,

$f \equiv 1$.

We receive

$\overline{\int_\gamma f(z)dz} = \overline{\int_\gamma 1 dz} = \overline{\gamma(1)-\gamma(0)} = -i$

$\int_\gamma\overline{f(z)}dz = \int_\gamma 1dz = \gamma(1)-\gamma(0) = i$.

Comment: Ah right, the RHS actually doesn't equal the result I got necessarily! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, take $f(z) = z, \gamma (t) = e^{it}, 0 \le t \le 2\pi.$

Added: In fact, if $\gamma $ is any simple closed contour, then $\int_\gamma z\,dz = 0, \int_\gamma \bar {z}\,dz \ne 0.$ (That the last integral is nonzero comes from Green's theorem: it equals $\pm$ the area enclosed.)